# How to automatically update dates in past tasks based on the start date on a task in MS Project

Tags: project-management, ms-project

I have a Project file with 30 tasks registered and they are all set to Automatically Schedule.

I have tasks done until task number 10, so I want to set the task number 11 start date as Today, but I want the past tasks, from 1 to 10, to have its dates automatically updated.

When I just click on the start date of task number 11 and change to Today, Project creates a "No earlier than" constraint, but that is not what I want.

Could someone help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A task's scheduled start date is calculated using the following:

- relationships (e.g. predecessors)
- constraints (e.g. "Start No Earlier Than")
- calendars (e.g. which days are working days)

If Task 11 has no predecessors and no constraints, it will default to start on the first working day after the project start date. If you want it to start today, use a constraint or drive the date by setting a Finish-to-Start relationship to a task that completed yesterday.